# Internal Salesforce bug: "Cannot grant or remove a profile with modify all data, without having the modify all data permission yourself."

Tags: platform-bug, gack

We receive "Cannot grant or remove a profile with modify all data,
without having the modify all data permission yourself." exception message when it shouldn't appear.

When there are two users, User Test 1 and User Test 2. User Test 2 has a permission set assigned with "Modify All Data" permission (but doesn't have that permission at profile level). User Test 1 doesn't have  "Modify All Data" permission either in profile or in permission sets. When User Test 1 tries to perform dummy update of User Test 2 (no fields are changed or modified), an error is thrown "Cannot grant or remove a profile with modify all data,
without having the modify all data permission yourself." even though no change in profile happens.

I am not sure if I should open Salesforce support ticket or is there any way to workaround this bug? I don't want to give  "Modify All Data" permission to User Test 1.

=========

Dummy update is like `update new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId())`, so no fields are changed

I would also provide a screen capturing video to explain that I do not use any code but rather I just update user from UI
[image]

Comment: Personally I'd recommending going ahead and logging a case. But given the poor response time of salesforce support, I'd continue searching for a work around you can implement.

Comment: I don't understand the "Dummy update" part, Can you please elaborate?

Comment: yes, dummy update is like update new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId()), so no fields are changed

Comment: I added a screen capturing video to explain better

Comment: What did you use to make your capture? Thats kinda cool and I think would help clarify alot of people's questions.

Comment: First of all, I either use Camtasia Studio or native Windows 10 screen capturing tool to record screen then I use website to convert mp4 video file into gif image, since you can't upload a video here

Comment: @RalphCallaway, yes, I have logged a case on Monday, firstly Salesforce Support replied to me that this is by design, but after I talked to the manager of that Salesforce Support lady and explained that even though a user doesn't have modify all data permission, still this user can update another user who has modify all data permission in profile but not assigned by a permission set, and after that they started investigation but didn't reply anything yet to me. They keep saying that they don't have any updates from Tier 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have opened a case in Salesforce Support.
Initially they said that this is expected behavior but later in a month time they have found [a known issue with Reference W-2922695](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000188hiQAA) they have discovered themselves in February.

Meanwhile we have found another workaround for our particular problem.
We used automated process to update users from a user who doesn't have Modify All permission.
We ended up writing a custom Apex Rest Service class to run in System context (without sharing) and we call that Apex Rest service class from a user who doesn't have Modify All permission in the automated process and it works for us for now. I think that if this was added to known issue list of workarounds then this might help another Salesforce customers who face the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you are making this from apex code you can try to make the update of the 
User record in system mode, that is, by declaring the corresponding apex class as  `without sharing`.

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: I did this from UI, the user who updates the record, doesn't have Author Apex permission

Comment: @Patlatus Is it really necessary for you to make this update? I don't see the reason why you want to do it.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. we have automated process which performs automatical update even if no fields is changed, and this platform bug is blocker for our functionality